# Increase Bandwidth live555 H264 RTSP Streaming

Tags: rtsp, rtp, live555

I want to stream H.264 RTSP using live555.
Previously, when using JRTPLIB, I was able to have about 150Mbps with a packet size of 65535 bytes and a packet-to-packet delay of 1/300 seconds. (But there was a packet loss of 0.3%.)

In live555, when I increase the packet size, the packet transmission time interval seems to increase, and the resulting throughput seems to be similar to the first.
How can we increase the bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be careful when increasing the packet size. You will not gain any performance benefits if you increase the packet size beyond the MTU size which is 1500 bytes usually and may vary device to device. Setting 65K packet size would not work, MTU will always be far less than that, and it will anyhow be fragmented by the underlying transport. You will have packet loss if you do so, in fact it will further deteriorate the performance. I'm able to achieve 60fps in realtime, and able to reach up to 120 fps with 1500 packet size itself.